# Ruby How To Create Ranges From Custom Objects Docs?

Tags: ruby, documentation

I was trying to find out how to create Ranges from custom objects in Ruby.  I am very new to Ruby and I found the documentation on Range not to be helpful.

The error I was receiving when trying to create a Range from my objects was simply "Bad Value For A Range".

I eventually figured out after far to long, that in order to create a range from my object, I must define the "succ" and "<=>" functions.

My question is this.  Is there a good resource that would have told me that I needed to define the above 2 functions in order to use my object in a range?  I'd like to avoid problems like this in the future.

Sorry for the unconventional question.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pickaxe Book (AKA "Programming Ruby") [has this to say about Range](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_stdtypes.html#S3):

> So far we've shown ranges of numbers and strings. However, as you'd expect from an object-oriented language, Ruby can create ranges based on objects that you define. **The only constraints are that the objects must respond to `succ` by returning the next object in sequence and the objects must be comparable using `<=>`, the general comparison operator.**

Emphasis mine. You have to be careful though, the Pickaxe that you'll find online is rather old and sometimes it doesn't agree with the current state of Ruby. There is an [updated version for Ruby 1.9](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781934356081.do) but I don't think that one is freely available online so you'd have to buy a copy.

I usually end up digging through the Ruby source to figure out a lot of these things. That applies doubly so to Rails.

Comment: https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/range.rb#L108 and https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/range.rb#L156 support your statements.

Comment: @Tass: Looks like Rubinius even has the Fixnum optimizations that MRI has in its C implementation. Thanks for the links.

Comment: Actually, I think `#succ` is only used by `Range#each`, so if you don't iterate over the range (and don't use any `Enumerable` methods, obviously), then you only need `<=>`. I haven't tried it, though, but the fact that you can build a range of `Float`s seems to suggest that.

Comment: @Jörg: The required interface for rangeable things is a bit ambiguous.  If you're just using it as an interval then you can get away with just `<=>` but then you don't really have a Range at all as your crippled-Range won't support the full Range interface. There should be two separate classes: Interval and Range. Interval would only require a well ordered domain, Range would also require enumerability.